# Howto make 1 pocket of the same id from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$a = [["product"=>"another2", "id"=>112],["product"=>"xyz", "id"=>113], ["product"=>"lmn", "id"=>113],["product"=>"abc", "id"=>113],  ["product"=>"another", "id"=>112]];

$data = [];
$products = [];

foreach ($a as $b) {

  $products[]["product"] = $b["product"];

  $data[$b["id"]] = $products;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

and the output is

```
  Array ( [112] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => another2 ) [1] => Array ( [product] => xyz ) [2] => Array ( [product] => lmn ) [3] => Array ( [product] => abc ) [4] => Array ( [product] => another ) ) [113] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => another2 ) [1] => Array ( [product] => xyz ) [2] => Array ( [product] => lmn ) [3] => Array ( [product] => abc ) ) )
```

i want to make 1 pocket of same ids. 
make 1 pocket if id is 112 from all array. for example i need

```
Array
(
    [112] => Array
        (


            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => xyz
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product] => lmn
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [product] => abc
                )



        )

    [113] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => another
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product] => another2
                )

                           )
        )
)
```

How can I get this output ? can anyone help me to make this possible. I need 1 array if the id is the same as it makes another array when the id is differents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You don't need to define the `$products` each time. Just loop on the array (saving the `$k` as the key) and assign.

Consider:

```
$a = [["product"=>"another2", "id"=>112],["product"=>"xyz", "id"=>113], ["product"=>"lmn", "id"=>113],["product"=>"abc", "id"=>113],  ["product"=>"another", "id"=>112]];

$data = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $b) {
  $data[$b["id"]][$k]["product"] =  $b["product"];
}
```

Now `$data` will be your desire output.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ZSmQP)

Answer (score 1):

Check below working code:

```
$a = [["product"=>"another2", "id"=>112],["product"=>"xyz", "id"=>113], ["product"=>"lmn", "id"=>113],["product"=>"abc", "id"=>113],  ["product"=>"another", "id"=>112]];

$products = [];

foreach ($a as $b) {    
  $products[$b["id"]][]["product"] = $b["product"];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($products);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$arr1 = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
 if(array_key_exists($v['id'], $arr1))
    $arr1[$v['id']][]['product'] = $v['product'];
 else
    $arr1[$v['id']][]['product'] = $v['product'];
}
```